# express routing run from post to next get is not automatically

Tags: node.js, express

I have following route defined:

`router.post('/select', function(req, res, next){
    var sql = "SELECT metadocid, col1, col2, col3 FROM mdt1 where ";
    var metadocid = req.body.metadocid;
    var op1 = req.body.op1;`

`if (metadocid !== "") {
        var opm = req.body.op1;
        switch (opm){
               case "equals":
                   opm = "=";
                   break;
               }
        var sel1 = "metadocid "  + opm + " " + metadocid;
    }
    sql = sql + sel1;
    console. log('Send sql: ' + sql );
    async.waterfall(
    [
      function(callback) {
       fs.writeFile('message.txt', sql, callback);
      }
    ], function (err) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('Appended text!');
    });

    next();
  });`

`router.get('/documents', function(req,res){
    handleAllDepartments(1);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/docs.html');
});`

`app.use('/',router);`

But from router.post('/select') it is not started the router.get('/documents'). If I type in browser the route /documents then
the programm continue to run.
I want the programm continue from router.post('/select') to router.get('/documents') automatically.

Please help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It won't happen because you want router to go from `POST` router to `GET`. And this is wrong.

Comment: Hi, I have route.get('/select') where it is a form with a few parameters to  build a sql-query string. Then in route.post('/select') I read the parametere from form and I write the sql-query in a file.

Comment: You have to remember that you have that `/select` parameter as well. This is another thing (after request method type) that will block to execute `/documents`.

You should really organize your requests differently because this is really messy what you attempt to do.

Comment: Hi, I have route.get('/select') where it is a form with a few parameters to  build a sql-query string. 
Then in route.post('/select') I read the parametere from form and I write the sql-query in a file. 
Then I have other route.get('/documents') where I start the sql-query from first route and present 
the results in a form, where the user can check what record he want.

Comment: Then in route.post('/documents') I read the checked info from form and present the document in browser. 
How can I go automatically from route ('select') to route ('documents') ? 
I have assumed that with next() I can go automatically from route.post('/select') to route.get('/documents').

Comment: And these all 4 routes should be executed with one single request? Or 4 separate?

Comment: If is possible with one request. But I have two distinct forms to read.

Answer (score 0):

The point of routing in Express is that if you call e.g. `POST /select`, the router will call only functions assigned to this and ONLY this request. This means that use of `next()` won't pass execution to for example `GET /select` or `POST /documents` or `GET /documents` because those are different requests.

There is method called `use` in Express that allows you to catch EVERY request without caring about method and address. It allows also use of next() of course.

To sum up, you have to call 4 separate requests to each of those you described in comments (and that's a lot) or simply make one request that will handle all those operations you were about to conduct in 4 routers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me from your code why you're doing things this way.  It looks like you're trying to post some data to a file, and then send a separate document down to the client.  This is a slightly uncommon workflow, though certainly doable.

The more common way to handle POST in a RESTful architecture like Express is to take the POST in one handler, and respond with a redirect to the newly POST'ed resource, which the client would then separately request with a GET.

That said, if you do have a workflow where you first post some data and then want to call some other function to handle the response, then you can use multiple handlers on a route like so:

```
function receiveDocData(req,res,next){
  var sql = "SELECT metadocid, col1, col2, col3 FROM mdt1 where ";
    var metadocid = req.body.metadocid;
    var op1 = req.body.op1;

  if (metadocid !== "") {
        var opm = req.body.op1;
        switch (opm){
               case "equals":
                   opm = "=";
                   break;
               }
        var sel1 = "metadocid "  + opm + " " + metadocid;
    }
    sql = sql + sel1;
    console. log('Send sql: ' + sql );
    async.waterfall(
    [
      function(callback) {
       fs.writeFile('message.txt', sql, callback);
      }
    ], function (err) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('Appended text!');
    });

    next();
  }
}

function doTheNextThing(req,res){
  handleAllDepartments(1);
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/docs.html');
}


router.post('/select', receiveDocData, doTheNextThing);
router.get('/documents', doTheNextThing);
app.use('/',router);
```

Note that I left the route for '/documents' on the assumption from your setup that you would want to get it independent of doing the actions in the original '/select' handler.